# Is it possible to use cross-package Template helpers with meteorhacks:ssr

Tags: meteor, wkhtmltopdf

I am currently using meteorhacks:ssr along with wkhtmltopdf in order to generate downloadable pdfs within my Meteor app.  It is working end-to-end, which is great, apart from one last element.

The template helpers which have been specified in packages across my app, are not visible.  From the examples in the documentation for SSR it uses templates and helpers specified at a super-package level, which is not feasible with a package based arrangement for an app.

The only way I can see to make them available both client and server-side is to store the functions in an object, and then to loop through the helper functions in client and server code to render the functions accessible in both places.

That methodology works, but it is rather lacking in beauty.  Does anyone have any other experience/ideas with this?

Comment: Can you show your current attempt and explain exactly what is wrong with it? If it's simply "beauty" then your question is too opinion-based for SO.

Comment: Kyli - thanks for the thoughts/comments/feedback, I will amend the question to include some code.  I suppose if it works, it works, I just figured there may be a better way to do it. I know that ReactLayout has SSR support but BlazeLayout does not, and although I am not using these, it may help if I did, to write less code, and store helpers functions in more than one place, and based on their client/server/both status, which adds complexity that can lead to simple problems, that can be annoying to debug.